# when subtracting two datetime objects tostring fails

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a timespan and format it but I get an error with the arguments on the tostring.

the model:

```
public DateTime? TimeToStart;
```

the formatter:

```
if (Model.TtsTimer.TimeToStart != null)
{
    ttsTime = (DateTime.Now - Model.TtsTimer.TimeToStart).ToString("h:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Comment: You need to use the `Value` property of the `DateTime?` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to subtract a `DateTime` from a `Nullable<DateTime>`. Try

```
ttsTime = (DateTime.Now - Model.TtsTimer.TimeToStart.Value).ToString(@"h\:m", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```